# Does Boost/Python have a make_array method?

Tags: c++, python, arrays, boost

I'd like to return to Python the results of my computations in a ndarray object. I know there is a `make_tuple` method so I figure there might be something similar for arrays though I can't find it.

Edit - I guess I can create the array in python, pass it as an extra parameter and modify it to hold the values. Would be better to use a return value though.

Answer (score 1):

Try `boost::python::numeric::array`:
 http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/libs/python/doc/v2/numeric.html#array-spec

Numeric is the former name of NumPy. It's possible that this wrapper still works with NumPy. Boost::Python seems to be notorious for having out of date documentation.

Comment: Do you know of a sample/tutorial with one being created? So far I've settled with just passing an extra parameter and storing the value there. I couldn't make sense out of the documentation link you posted. I'm already using it btw, I just can't understand how to create a ndarray from the c++ code.

Comment: Yes but the documentation on that page is dreadful. They just copy in the already commentless header, don't explain any of the methods or what they do, and the example is useless. Programmers want to know how to pass C++ data collections back to the user as numpy objects. They don't show you how.